# Find maximum value of a function using php

Tags: php, mathematical-optimization

How can I get maximum value of a function in specific range with php.
For example I have a function:

```
function f($x){
    return pow($x,2);
}
```

and i want to get maximum value of this function in range (-1,1).
how can I implement this in php or using some other library?

Comment: You cannot generalize problem, so try to find analytical method to look for global maximum: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no generic way to do this; you have to do the maths yourself.

Maximisation / Minimisation problems are solved by differentiation. In this case, you would get:

```
d(x^2)/dx = 2*x
```

The method for calculating the differential depends on your function. It's not that hard for simple functions like this, and Wolfram Alpha (http://www.wolframalpha.com/) will do it for you if you ask it nicely (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%28x%5E2%29%2Fdx).

Then you set that to 0, which tells you when the gradient is 0 (and therefore, it is at a maximum, minimum, or turning point):

```
2*x = 0
```

This tells you that you have a point to check at `x = 0` (see the "solution" section here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%28x%5E2%29%2Fdx%3D0). Now check the value of your function at the lower bound, upper bound, and the point(s) this tells you to check, and get the maximum/minimum of all those results. This will be your limit within that range.

Comment: the problem is that I don't know the exact form of the function, it is created according to user input.

Comment: Do you know the general form? There are algebraic ways to solve many common functions. For example, `a*x^b + c*x^d` => `a*b*x^(b-1) + c*d*x^(d-1)`. The basic rules are easy to learn and implement (of course, Alpha is able to go *way* further, but they've been building that for decades).

Comment: A method commonly used is to approximate the gradient by checking several points around a starting point (and you should repeat this method many times for different starting points), then follow the gradient to the *local maximum / minimum*. It gets quite complicated. For example, you can find zeros which are near a starting point by applying Newton's method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method#Description

Comment: But can I include Wolfram Alpha functionality into my php file, because I want to get maximum value of a function during the program run.

Comment: Ha, well you could try, although I'm pretty sure they do their best to block that sort of behaviour. You can *buy* its abilities. I think this is the place to start: http://products.wolframalpha.com/developers/ it's apparently free for personal use. But it's a bit of a sledgehammer-to-hammer-in-a-nail job. I'd suggest learning the techniques. They'll come in handy time and again.

Comment: If you don't have derivatives, but your function evaluation is cheap why don't you just use a secant method (which you can think of as a form of Newton's method with approximate derivatives). It should be relatively easy to code in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$maximumValue = -999999999;
for ($i = -1; $i <= 1; $i++) {
    $maximumValue = max($maximumValue, f($i));
}
var_dump($maximumValue);
```

..should work fine

This will only check for the numbers `-1`, `0` and `1`. If you want more precision, just change `$i++` to eg. `$i += 0.1`:

```
$maximumValue = -999999999;
for ($i = -1; $i <= 1; $i += 0.1) {
    $maximumValue = max($maximumValue, f($i));
}
var_dump($maximumValue);
```

This will give you `-1`, `-0.9`, `-0.8` ..... `0.8`, `0.9` and `1`.

It could also be changed to `$i += 0.000000001` if you want to waste a lot of resources, but get a more accurate result.

Comment: This will only find it if it happens to be an integer. Not generally the case.

Comment: @Dave That is true, but I assumed that the OP wanted it to be able to attach to any sort of function. Of course `$i++` could be changed to `$i += 0.00001` if one wanted to.

Comment: @Dave: `pow` will always return an int or float, `max` will cast and compare correctlyAFAIK

Comment: Why only three (-1, 0, 1) arguments?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the OP stated the function was an example, not the actual function he wanted to evaluate. And if it were, there are much more efficient ways to find the max/min of pow. Besides, what I meant was it only checks -1, 0 and 1. It doesn't check x=0.5, for example.

Comment: @h2ooooooo (r.e. `$i += 0.00001`) Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhh! It hurts! NO. Bad. Don't do that.

Comment: @Dave: I'm not for a second going to argue that this is the way to go, I merely wanted to point out that `max` works on floats, too. Your comment came across as though it doesn't. As far as this brute-force asnwer is concerned... Noooo way.

Comment: @h2ooooooo there could be a function that has its maximum at exactly 0.000001. your idea wouldn't find that maximum!

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem OK, I can see the confusion, but that wasn't my concern.

Answer (score 0):

If you use differentiation you have to deal with the case that there are no local optima.  If the function is smooth this would mean that the optima occur on the endpoints.  I am not sure how precise this all needs to be,but perhaps if the function is just given by a finite list of pairs you could sort a list which contains all the points where the function is defined.

Comment: No it's infinite: it is defined on [0,1] segment. I only know that it is one variable function and is continuous on [0,1].

Comment: If you know its continuous pick an error.  Then pick n so that 1/n is less than the error.  Now divide the interval like so:

Comment: If you know its continuous pick an error.  Then pick n so that 1/n is less than the error.  Now divide the interval like so [0, 1/2, 2/n, ..., 1].  Now define a list, L=[f(0), f(1/2), ..., f(1)], and sort this list.  Notice that a function continuous on a compact interval is uniformly continuous so this is reasonable. (Uniformly continuous means that for a certain desired error in the range, that there is one number delta such that if |x-y |< delta then |f(x) -f(y)|<error). If it's not continuous near some point this won't work.

Comment: Currently my program is running that way. But I need very exact max value. So for n=100 my program is running very slowly. For even bigger numbers I have memory leak.